# Can I test Electron application using Playwright Python library?

Tags: electron, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-python

I have a **desktop application** developed with **Electron**.
I tested it with Selenium and it works perfectly.
Now I am discovering **Playwright** library.

My question is: can I use the Playwright Python library to test my Electron application?

PS: I haven't found any documentation about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not yet possible but there is a feature request for it here: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python/issues/379

Comment: I'm using RobotFramework to test my desktop application. I found the [Browser library](https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html) (The Browser library uses the Playwright Node module to automate web testing with a single library)
-  But it seems that the python version of playwright is new (many features are not yet included: the Browser library does not include the test of an Electron application) 
- On the other side [we can test Electron app using Playwright in nodeJS version](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/automated-testing#using-playwright)